# Drupal 7 - Most Appropriate Way to Create Multiple Custom Menu Items Via Code

Tags: php, menu, drupal-7, menuitem

I currently have a custom menu item that was created with the code below and it works great:

```
function myModule_menu(){
    $items = array();

    $items['myModule'] = array(
        'title' => 'Business Owner Dashboard',
        'page callback' => '_custom_page',
        'access arguments' => array('use_business_dashboard'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

    return $items;
}
```

The thing is I want to create multiple menu items for multiple roles, not just one. I assume I can used a switch case somehow, but I am unsure how and cannot find any documentation on the topic.

Just to clarify, I want to use the same myModule_menu() function to set up the "Business Owner Dashboard" as well as another menu item called "Referrals" with different "page callback", "access arguments", etc. Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple to add more menu items - just define another element in the `$items` array:

```
function myModule_menu() {
    $items['admin/business'] = array(
        'title' => 'Business',
        'description' => 'Business.',
        'page callback' => '_administer_business',
        'access arguments' => array('administer business'),
        'file' => 'business.admin.inc', //if the page callback function is in another file
    );
    if (referrals_allowed) {
        $items['admin/referrals'] = array(
            'title' => 'Referals',
            'description' => 'Referrals.',
            'page callback' => '_administer_referrals',
            'access arguments' => array('administer referrals'),
            'file' => 'referrals.admin.inc', //if the page callback function is in another file
        );
    }

    return $items;
}
```